# VBA Excel "Compile error: Object Required" on Sub Declaration

Tags: excel, vba

So this code worked fine last week but i have changed my source folder and now getting this error. Really no idea why.

I click on a button to execute the main sub which prompts the user for a folder path and then loops through each folder to do a series of actions.

the Error is thrown on the sub call

```
    Private Sub LoopThroughFiles() --- error here 424
 
Dim oFolder As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim oFSO As Object
Dim i As Integer




Set oFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
 
Set oFolder = oFSO.GetFolder(sFolderPath)
Writelog "Initializing"

For Each oFile In oFolder.Files
Writelog "Starting Import on File " & oFile.Name

    Dim wbCopy As Workbook
    Dim wbDest As Workbook
    Dim wsCopy As Worksheet
    Dim wsDest As Worksheet
    Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
    Dim lDestLastRow As Long
    Dim Provider As String
    
    

  'Set variables for copy and destination sheets
  Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(oFile.Path)
  Writelog "File Opened " & oFile.Name
  Set wsCopy = wbCopy.Worksheets("Quantitative Disclosures")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
  Set Provider = wbCopy.Worksheets("Cover").Cells("H3").Value
  '1. Find last used row in the copy range based on data in column A
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    
  '2. Find first blank row in the destination range based on data in column A
  'Offset property moves down 1 row
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  '3. Copy & Paste Data
  wsCopy.Range("M1:M" & lCopyLastRow).Copy
  wsDest.Range("B" & lDestLastRow).PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
  Writelog "Copying of Data completed from File " & oFile.Name & Provider
  
  '4 Copy the provider name
  wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow) = Provider
  Writelog "Provider data copied from File " & oFile.Name & Provider

  '5 Close Currently open workbook
    wbCopy.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Writelog "File Closed " & oFile.Name & Provider
    
Next oFile

 'Delete all emoty Columns
  Delete_Empty_Columns
 Writelog "Deleted Empty Columns  - DataSheet"
 

 
End Sub
```

the Sub is called here

```
Sub Main()

SelectFolder
LoopThroughFiles

End Sub
```

the select folder sub is here

```
Private Sub SelectFolder()

    ' Open the select folder prompt
    With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
        If .Show = -1 Then ' if OK is pressed
            sFolderPath = .SelectedItems(1)
        End If
    End With
    Writelog "Folder Selected " & sFolderPath
End Sub
```

the sFolderPath string is a global public variable

Comment: This feels wrong: `Set Provider = wbCopy.Worksheets("Cover").Cells("H3").Value` The `Value` of a cell is just a string, therefore `Set` shouldn't be used, and if you attempted this it would likely result in that error.

Comment: @JNevill thanks that has removed that error, although now I have another error on that line  - Invalid Procedure call or argument `Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("DataSheet")
  Provider = wbCopy.Worksheets("Cover").Cells("H3").Value`

Comment: Are both of those lines on the same line? Those should be two separate lines. All you are doing is removing the `Set` on that Provider line.

Comment: yeah they are separated, I fixed it by changing the `cells("h3")` to `range("h3")`

Comment: @Rhyno_H It's also a bit faster to use ```.Value2``` rather than ```.Value```. It doesn't make a large difference for one call, but using it in loops it has a noticeable effect.

Comment: thanks all, would have been good if i could vote for your comments, but really appreciate the help!